# Variable replacement using regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace a variable in a file (temp.txt) in Perl.

**temp.txt**

```
Hi  $test. How are you??
```

I want to replace the variable `$test` together with it's value. I want to replace the string `$test` in a file with `abc`.  This is the code I tried:

```
open my $filename, "<", temp.txt or die $!;

while (<$filename>) 
{ 
   s/$test/'abc'/g;
   print;
}
```

It is not working. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the string `$test`, or the string contained in the variable named `$test`? Because your code is doing the latter. `use strict; use warnings;` will inform you of this mistake.

Comment: You need to escape the `$` in the pattern.

Comment: `$` in a regex means end of line. To match a literal dollar sign, backslash-escape it, or put it in a character class. `s/\$test/'abc'/` or `s/[$]test/'abc'/`

Comment: That is a rather bad idea, if you intend to use a variable named `$test` to store the value. There are better ways to use templates. Such as [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Toolkit.pod).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.. backslash-escaping it or putting it in a character class doesn't seem to solve the purpose.I have never used Template::Toolkit. Let me try and read about it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `$` because Perl thinks `$test` is a variable:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/\$test/'abc'/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Hi  $test. How are you??
```